# PL/SQL How do i remove characters from data

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have rows that contain certain data such as:

```
EUR-40E
CP1-40E
CP1-36E
CP1FP-48E
```

My question is, how do i remove all characters leaving only the numbers after the hyphen.

I have tried to do it using this:

`REGEXP_REPLACE (po.config_id, '\D')`

But end up with this output:

```
140
140
136
```

It takes all characters but unfortunately the 1 before the hyphen remains?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

`select regexp_replace(substr(text,instr(text,'-'),length(text)), '[^0-9]', '') from dual;`

replace `text` with the actual value e.g. `CP1FP-48E56T`

Example ( I created a dummy table `foo` with your values ) :

```
SQL> select * from foo;

TEXT
------------
EUR-40E
CP1-40E
CP1-36E
CP1FP-48E
CP1FP-48E54R

SQL> select regexp_replace(substr(text,instr(text,'-'),length(text)), '[^0-9]', '') output from foo;

OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
40
40
36
48
4854
```

Comment: Fantastic! I actually changed the Text to the column name and it's done it perfectly! Thanks @vishnud

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like that:

```
select substr(regexp_substr('EUR-40E','-[[:digit:]]+'),2) from dual;
```

Comment: Hi @sers. Thanks for that. I believe it's taking 'EUR-40E' and returning that against all rows. I was expecting it to return 40, 40, 36, 48 from the examples above. I got 40, 40, 40, 40.

Comment: Hey @Kay, just used  'EUR-40E' as an example and place holder - of course you have to replace it with the actual strings you want to convert! :-)

Comment: Hi @sers. Yes, i retried your query and it was good! That was my mistake ^.^

Comment: Upvoting, as this is a valid answer too :)